# Difference between artifact.clazz and bean.class

Tags: grails, groovy

In my grails project some of controllers' actions annotated with custom annotation, say CustomAnnotation.
Also, there is a filter that checks controllers' actions whether they annotated by CustomAnnotation or not.

I've tried two ways to perform this check:

1) Look for annotations of bean's class methods

```
def artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", controllerName)
def controller = applicationContext.getBean(artefact.clazz.name)
def actionMethod = controller.class.declaredMethods.find { it.name == actionName }
def isAnnotated = actionMethod.isAnnotationPresent(CustomAnnotation)
```

2) Look for annotations of artifact's clazz methods

```
def artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", controllerName)
def actionMethod = artefact.clazz.declaredMethods.find { it.name == actionName }
def isAnnotated = actionMethod.isAnnotationPresent(CustomAnnotation)
```

While the first way doesn't work for me, the second works well.
Why these classes are different and what is the difference?

Comment: In the first one, what's the result of `controller.getClass().name`?

Comment: something like custom.package.CustomController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a131be82

Comment: Both of them worked for me in grails console (v2.2.0) with a minute change of `applicationContext` to `grailsApplication.mainContext`. [Example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6838238/).

Comment: So the difference is that controller is a proxy in 1, but is the concrete class in 2.

Comment: @Sergio Michels: You're right, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the comment in answer, the difference can be clarified by printing the class of the controller:

In the first case, the bean class is a proxy:`custom.package.CustomController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a131be82` you can notice that by the "EnhacerByCGLIB" part. In the second one the class is correct.